# Calculate the diffrence between compare price and subtotal in shopify cart page

Tags: php, shopify, shopify-template

How to calculate the "compare price" of all products and Comparison between "subtotal and compare price" of all products in shopify cart page?

Comment: please add your code to description

Comment: {% for item in cart.items %}                  
                {% if item.product.compare_at_price > item.price %}
                  <s>{{ item.product.compare_at_price | money }}</s>
                {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}  //This code display the compare price of each product.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `add` or `minus` to add to subtract the values and `assign` to assign a value to a variable

```
{% assign total_cart_item_price = 0 %}
{% assign total_cart_compare_price = 0 %}

{% for item in cart.items %} 

    {% if item.product.compare_at_price > item.price %} 
    <s>
        {{ item.product.compare_at_price | money }}
    </s> 
    {% endif %}

     {% assign total_cart_item_price = total_cart_item_price | plus: item.price %}
     {% assign total_cart_compare_price = total_cart_compare_price | plus: item.variant.compare_at_price %}
{% endfor %}

{% assign total_difference = total_cart_item_price | minus: total_cart_compare_price %}

<h1>Total Cart Compare price {{total_cart_compare_price}}</h1>
<h1>Total cart price {{total_cart_item_price}}</h1>
<h1>Total Difference {{total_difference}}</h1>
```

Comment: You would probably want to use `item.variant.compare_at_price` (instead of `item.product.compare_at_price`) - if there are multiple variants with different prices or compare-at prices, the value on the `product` object is the lowest out of all the variants (which might not necessarily be the one in the cart)

Comment: Thank you for this information Dave B. I will update the answer.

Comment: Thanks for Reply @RajKumar

Comment: Welcome Dyna. If this solves your problem, you may mark this as answer :)